# Should I question myself if I did something wrong?

Tags: job-change, france

I'm 20 years old, got a degree in business and that field of activity didn't worked well for me, never found a way to keep studying it (I actually wanted to do scientific degree). Now, I took a 7 month bootcamp on Java, but only the basics. Now this bootcamp was funded by two companies. One offered me a job and the other to keep studying for one year.

Well I went for the first one, I don't think it was the wisest choice but here I am.

The problem now, the company I worked with didn't validate my approval period on it's last day. Even though I was already on a mission for a client. I was enrolled on this mission with another colleague that did the same bootcamp with me. We had to make a software project and we actually kinda did it, with the help of our lead developer.

Now as I said, they didn't validate my contract with the company. I was told, I'm not enough rigorous, autonomous and they seemed to accentuate the fact that I was kinda young, too young for their company and that I should feel better in other places.

Now for me it seems like a lie, or something because in France, the employer has to warn you 1 week before the approval period ends, otherwise they have to pay you one weeks worth of salary after you leave. Which they decided to do for me.

And the way that was done seemed like they made the decision the night before the day they announced that to me.

Am I wrong? I asked my friend who got validated and he said, from what he understood from the team that my technical skills and such wasn't the problem but mostly the fact that I wouldn't fit in the company's mold.

Comment: Hello, welcome to The Workplace. Please read [how to ask](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so you get a better idea on what topics are OK to ask here... I suggest that you try to summarize or cut the not-so-relevant details on your post, to make it more understandable, and to rephrase the question you are asking (currently, am I wrong? which is off-topic for the site)... I will now attempt to edit your post to try summarize it. Feel free to further edit it

Comment: I took an edit to your post and made it more concise. Please, rephrase your question to something we can answer to make it completely on-topic. We can't really answer if "you are wrong"... but we can help you make a plan on what to do now, or what would have been the proper steps so you learn from this, or something like that...

Comment: As phrased, this is kind of asking for advice on a specific choice, which is off-topic here. Can you [edit] to make this more broadly applicable?

Comment: They apparently have a stated preference for employees to be older than you, yet you impressed them enough they were on the edge about giving you the approval. So you didn't get this one, but you were still impressive. Keep your spirits up and you'll get a good job before too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I asked my friend who got validated and he said, from what he understood from the team that my technical skills and such wasn't the problem but mostly the fact that I wouldn't fit in the company's mold.

This is the purpose of a probation or approval period:

- to confirm your skills are up to the standard required for the role;
- to see how well you fit with the team and company culture.

The company is free to not extend your work agreement after the probation if they feel you don't "fit in".

> I'm not enough rigorous, autonomous and they seemed to accentuate the fact that I was kinda young, too young for their company

Again, this sounds more like a cultural fit problem rather than simple skill - although rigour and autonomy can be improved on. Were you given any feedback during your probation to steer you?

> Now for me it seems like a lie

What rreason do they have to lie? They now have to pay you a week's worth of pay, without getting any work from you. They will now also have to go through the process of placing someone else in your position - which costs timers time and money.

If you can, try and get more detailed feedback from your supervisor. Ask for pointers on how to improve. Take the advice, and start looking for for next job.

Comment: Alright guys, sorry for the long delay of response.

Thanks for the answers. It's clearer to me. 

Although I can't have a feedback from them, I should have asked it back then.


Thanks for your time and answers.